# How to change default doctrine entity scheme?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

The default one to one relation scheme is

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    shipping_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Shipping (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Product ADD FOREIGN KEY (shipping_id) REFERENCES Shipping(id);
```

But I need to use this scheme but with it some modification `ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL;`:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    shipping_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Shipping (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Product ADD FOREIGN KEY (shipping_id) REFERENCES Shipping(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL;
```

Can I create this scheme with doctrine entity configuration?

P.S. I has two entities: `Vendor` and `Image`

```
BW\ShopBundle\Entity\Vendor:
    type: entity
    table: vendors
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    oneToOne:
        image:
            targetEntity: BW\FileBundle\Entity\Image
            cascade: [persist, remove]
```

and

```
BW\FileBundle\Entity\Image:
    type: entity
    table: images
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        filename:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
```

And I use a `oneToOne Unidirectional` relation.

So when I remove `Image` object, I has an error, becouse I had `Unidirectional` relation (And it's important to know that I can't to change relation to `bidirectional`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [Orphan Removal](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) ?

From the offcial documentation :

> There is another concept of cascading that is relevant only when removing entities from collections. If an Entity of type **A** contains references to privately owned Entities **B** then if the reference from **A** to **B** is removed the entity **B** should also be removed, because it is not used anymore.
>
> OrphanRemoval works with one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many associations

You chould use the `orphanRemoval=true` option like this :

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", orphanRemoval=true)
```

Comment: It's interesting, I will try to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onDelete="CASCADE"` to force the underlying database to remove all associated objects internally when you delete referencing entity.

Example:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="shipping_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
```

This detail also documented [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html).

Comment: Thanks, but it's not work in my case, because `onDelete="CASCADE"` not changed default schema

Comment: I add my example to question